# ¿Como puedo validar una fecha en java netbeans usando try catch?

Tags: java, netbeans, date, validación

Debo validar una fecha con el formato **DD/MM/AA** pero usando **excepciones try catch**.
La fecha debe ser ingresada en un jTextField y debe ser validad usando métodos con **try catch**

**Lo siguiente es un ejemplo de como validé la contraseña:**

```
//Esta es la clase donde creé la excepción
public class PASSWORD_EXCEPTION1 extends Exception{

    public PASSWORD_EXCEPTION1() {
    }

    public PASSWORD_EXCEPTION1(String string) {
        super(string);
    }
    
    
    public static void validarContra(String contra) throws PASSWORD_EXCEPTION1
    {
        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile();
        String PASSWORD_EXCEPTION =  "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])()(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,}$";
            
        boolean match= contra.matches(PASSWORD_EXCEPTION);
        if(!match)  throw new PASSWORD_EXCEPTION1("La contraseña "+ contra + " no es válida");
        
  
  }
}


//Aquí la estoy implementando en una acción FocusLost de un JTextField
private void jTextFieldCorreoFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                           
        try{
            EmailException email = new EmailException();
            email.validarEmail(jTextFieldCorreo.getText());
        } catch (EmailException ex3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex3.getMessage());
            jTextFieldCorreo.setText("");
            jTextFieldCorreo.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Format {
private static final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
private Date date;

Format(Date date){
    this.date = date;
}

Date getDateWithFormat(){
    try{
        date = format.parse(date.toString());
        return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad, saludos.